# How to use escape character in replace function when replacing quotations in VB

Tags: vb.net, escaping, character, quotations

Here is my code snippet:

```
 Public Function convert(ByVal robert As String)
        Try
            robert = Replace(robert, "U", "A")
            robert = Replace(robert, "\"", "A")
```

I want to actually replace the "quotations" with the A but the program doesn't seem to recognize the fact that I'm using an escape character in VB.  Does anyone know why?  Thanks!

Robert

**EDIT by rlbond86:** This is clearly Visual Basic code. I have changed the title and text to reflect that.

Comment: What language is this? This definitely doesn't look like C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like VB, not c++.

See http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-20709.html

you want to use:

```
robert = Replace(robert, chr(34), "A")
```

or

```
robert = Replace(robert, """", "A")
```

using " as escape character

also see: http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/index.php?title=Escape_sequences For info on escape sequences in multiple languages